# How to iterate in a for loop with error handling

Tags: python, for-loop, error-handling

I am trying to catch input errors from the user.  The input should be a float.  I cannot figure out the logic.

I want the user to redirected to the same key value in material_vars if they enter an invalid input.  Currently I can make it work so if an incorrectly it goes back to the first key input rather than the key the invalid entry occurred on.

```
def material_costs(update=False):

    global material_vars

    while update:

        try:
            for key in material_vars:
                material_vars[key] = float(input(f"Enter {key}:\n"))
        except ValueError:
            print ('Please enter a valid input')
        else:
            save_defaults('material_vars', material_vars)
            update = False

    else:
        material_vars = open_defaults('material_vars')
    return material_vars
```

Comment: What information are you storing in material_vars? Additionally, why is material_vars marked global inside of a function?

Comment: @Kickin_Wing material_var is a dict with 3 key value {'PLA': 20.95, 'PET-G': 27.0, 'ABS': 27.0}, i'm using  material_vars as global as i need that variable to be available in multiple places within the script. (i'm sure there is a better way to do that but is beyond my knowledge just yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your function like this

```
def material_costs(update=False):
    global material_vars
    while update:
        for key in material_vars:
            correct = False
            while (not correct):
                try:
                    material_vars[key] = float(input(f"Enter {key}:\n"))
                    correct = True
                except ValueError:
                    print ('Please enter a valid input')
                    correct = False
        save_defaults('material_vars', material_vars)
        update = False
    else:
        material_vars = open_defaults('material_vars')
    return material_vars
```

Run a while loop for each input until the user enters the correct input.
The input will be verified by the try-except blocks inside the while.

I hope this helps.